# Can I store and work with a directory in compressed form?

Tags: directory, tar

I have to work with many large sized directories which are shipped around in the form of tarballs. However, in order to really do any operations these tarballs have to be untarred into directories and operations are performed. Most operations involves coreutils or basic Linux commands in pipelines. Is it possible to work with these directories such that they are compressed?

Comment: What do you mean "work"? Like modify a file in the compressed dir or only copy a file out of it?

Comment: @ott-- I was expecting an ability to 'read' from the files and subdirectories directly from the tarball but surely an ability to write or modify would be great.

Comment: Try `mc` to dive into `tar.{gz,bz2}` or use the file manager that comes with your GUI. Both use `fuse`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Christopher suggested, `archivemount` can achieve this.  Permits writing of files and when unmounted, the .tar.gz file is automatically updated to reflect the changes.

```
# ls -lh download.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r--. 1 steve steve 3.1M Feb 16  2010 download.tar.gz
# archivemount download.tar.gz /mnt
# cd /mnt
# find . -ls|head
     1 3127 drwxr-xr-x   0 root     root      3201043 Dec 31  1969 .
     2    0 drwxr-xr-x   0 steve    steve           0 Aug 30  2006 ./kojoney
     3    0 drwxr-xr-x   0 steve    steve           0 Aug 30  2006 ./kojoney/reports
     4    0 drwxr-xr-x   0 steve    steve           0 Aug 30  2006 ./kojoney/reports/ip_country
     5    9 -rwxr-xr-x   0 steve    steve        9067 Dec 29  2006 ./kojoney/reports/ip_country/Geography-Countries-1.4.tar.gz
     6  160 -rw-r--r--   0 steve    steve      162827 Apr  6  2006 ./kojoney/reports/ip_country/IP-Country-2.21.tar.gz
#

# rpm -qi archivemount
Name        : archivemount
Version     : 0.8.1
Release     : 2.fc20
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Tue 21 Jul 2015 11:29:16 AM PDT
Group       : System Environment/Libraries
Size        : 75342
License     : LGPLv2+
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Sun 13 Oct 2013 11:44:05 AM PDT, Key ID 2eb161fa246110c1
Source RPM  : archivemount-0.8.1-2.fc20.src.rpm
Build Date  : Sun 13 Oct 2013 10:34:48 AM PDT
Build Host  : buildvm-10.phx2.fedoraproject.org
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : Fedora Project
Vendor      : Fedora Project
URL         : http://www.cybernoia.de/software/archivemount/
Summary     : FUSE based filesystem for mounting compressed archives
Description :
Archivemount is a piece of glue code between libarchive and FUSE. It can be
used to mount a (possibly compressed) archive (as in .tar.gz or .tar.bz2)
and use it like an ordinary filesystem.
#
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, thanks to [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), which allows filesystems to be implemented by userland programs. There are many FUSE filesystems out there, implementing files stored as something other than sectors on a disk, including alternate views of existing filesystems, files on a remote machine, files in an archive, etc.

You can use [archivemount](http://www.cybernoia.de/software/archivemount/) to mount a specific archive to a directory. The archives are modifiable.

```
mkdir foo
archivemount foo.tar.gz foo
ls foo
echo hello >foo/new-file
fusermount -u foo
rmdir foo
tar tf foo.tar.gz
```

You can use [avfs](http://avf.sourceforge.net/) to access all archives without having to perform a specific action for each archive. Avfs creates a view of the whole directory tree under `~/.avfs` where each archive has a companion directory `ARCHIVE-FILE#` that appears to contain the file's content. The archive content is read-only.

```
mountavfs
ls ~/.avfs$PWD/foo.tar.gz\#
```