# Opening files within archives from vim

Tags: vim, archive

I know that vim can open files within zip or tar{,.gz} archives interactively: open the archive first, then navigate to the correct entry and press enter.

lesspipe (https://github.com/wofr06/lesspipe) (which is a preprocessor for *less*) provides the additional convenience of allowing one to directly input both the archive name and the name of the file within the archive at the same time (`less foo.tgz:file-within-foo`) (yes, I know, such a scheme leads, in theory, to issues with files containing colons in their names; in practice this is rare...).  I was wondering if a similar ability was available (perhaps as a plugin) for vim.

Clarification: Fundamentally, what I'm asking for should be "relatively" simple (and mostly focused on a usability POV), because most of the archive-handling ability is actually already present in vim: I am just looking for a plugin that will transform, say, `vim foo.tgz:file-within` to `vim foo.tgz` followed by selecting `file-within` in the listing offered by vim.

Comment: you want to see the content of a `.rar` file from `vim` which is not possible. but `vim` can show the content of  zip or tar{,.gz}.

Comment: nope, `.tgz` is just `.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 1):

Most Unix variants support [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), which allows programs to define new filesystem types. There are several FUSE filesystems that expose archive contents as a directory tree. This way any application can see archive contents as ordinary files transparently. See [Can I store and work with a directory in compressed form?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217433/can-i-store-and-work-with-a-directory-in-compressed-form)

For example, with [avfs](http://avf.sourceforge.net/), you get read-only access:

```
mountavfs
cd ~/.avfs$PWD
vim foo.tgz\#/file-within-foo
```

With [archivemount](http://www.cybernoia.de/software/archivemount/), you need to mount each archive explicitly, but you get read-write access.

```
mkdir foo.d
archivemount foo.tgz foo.d
vim foo.d/file-within-foo
fusermount -u foo.d; rmdir foo.d
```